# Steam: Not rendering text on Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit

Tags: games, steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I report bugs/problems with Valve’s Steam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236773/where-do-i-report-bugs-problems-with-valves-steam)

I am having a problem with steam and games on my system. It seems to not be rendering any text. Here is a screenshot of what it look like

[image: http://imgur.com/a/xE6hp].

I am also getting a error in the console that looks like this http://pastebin.com/gQS70Avd .     I've tried re-install it but that did not seem to help.

Comment: This looks like a bug - assuming you are a beta user - they would like you to report bugs to the Steam team.

Comment: The problem is I don't think it is steams fault because the game I link is doing the same thing.

Comment: Judging from the error messages it looks like a problem with the graphics driver, as your X isn't using direct rendering. You can also try installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` which sometimes helps with font issues, but probably not here, can hurt either way.

Comment: I had the same issue (with native Steam beta client) and installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package resolved it.